# Pagination with mongodb using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I am trying to paginate my search results which i am fetching from `mongoDB`, i am using `mongoDB` aggregation, now the problem i am facing is that as i can use $skip and $limit to achieve pagination how can i know that next page exists or not. I used this logic where suppose i am showing 20 results in one page now i will call for 21 results and see if results are 21 or less than 21, if it is 21 then that means at least one result is left so next page is there otherwise no pages left. My code is given below and everything is working fine but i think as i am fetching every time one more document on my server so i think instead of using this approach can i possible write some logic in aggregation pipeline so that i don't have to bring one more document from my database. I mean is there any approach so that i can store 1 in a variable if results are more than 20 otherwise 0. I tried to use this logic by having a variable in $group and increment on every doc but was not able to perform the operation successfully.

There was another solution to run two query parallel first one to count number of docs and second one to fetch 20 docs but i don't think this approach is better as it would cost me one more database call.

My code with $skip and $limit to fetch 21 results per page is given below.

```
       studcouponsmodel.aggregate(
            { $match: { mobile_no: mobile_no }},
            { $unwind: '$cpns'},
            { $match: {'cpns.expir_date': { $lt: curr_time }}},
            { $group: {_id: '$mobile_no', cpns: {$push: '$cpns.id'}}},
            { $limit: page_size + 1 },
            { $skip: page * page_size },
            function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error Finding query results');
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json({success: 0, message : err});
                    return next(err);
                } else {

                }
            });
```

Can anyone please tell me any better approach or what have you all tried to paginate in `mongoDB` using aggregation.